# ancestry gem - a way to build the tree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ancestry

I have a menu which `has_many :menu_headers`. I'd like to just output the tree of `menu_headers`. Is there a way to do this via the gem rather than iterating through all the `menu_headers`?

#### edit 1

So I spent a few minutes this morning coming up with this but seems like there should be a pre-built way to do this:

```
  def menu_headers_tree tmp_menu_headers: nil
    tmp_menu_headers=menu_headers if tmp_menu_headers.nil?
    tmp=[]
    tmp_menu_headers.each_with_index do |mh,idx|
      puts mh.id
      tmp_obj={}
      tmp_obj[:name]=mh.name
      tmp_obj[:menu_headers]=[]
      tmp << tmp_obj
      if mh.children.count > 0
        puts "THERE is A menu_headers"
        tmp[idx][:menu_headers]=menu_headers_tree tmp_menu_headers: mh.children
      else
        puts "there is no menu_headers"
      end
    end
    return tmp
  end
```

Comment: You mean, show full tree in view?

Comment: y - added some really simple sample code